# Save test case properties if any of the assertions fail

Tags: groovy, soapui

How to save the test case properties if any of the assertions fail within this groovy script step?

Below is example code:

```
// define properties required for the script to run. 
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context) 
def dataFolder = groovyUtils.projectPath

def vTIDAPI = testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue("vTIDAPI")
def vTIDDB = testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue("vTIDDB")
def RefAPI = testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue("RefAPI")
def RefDB = testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue("RefDB")
def AmountAPI = testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue("AmountAPI")
def AmountDB = testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue("AmountDB")
def CurrencyAPI = testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue("CurrencyAPI")
def CurrencyDB = testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue("CurrencyDB")


assert vTIDAPI == vTIDDB
assert RefAPI == RefDB
assert AmountAPI == AmountDB
assert CurrencyAPI == CurrencyDB
```

Comment: Where is the issue in the mentioned script? Is it that you want to collect all the properties of test case when any of the assertion fails?

Comment: Yes I just want all the properties to be collected and stored in a file when collected. I posted the current code I have and remove my attempted version just so it will be easier for the person who answer to provide their method of tackling this scenario

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139652/room-for-rao-and-bruceybandit

Comment: BruceyBandit, have you got chance to try the solution provided below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the `Groovy Script` which does compare the given set of properties and on any of the assertion failure, writes the properties to a given file.

- You need to change the value of property file name to be stored for variable `propFileName` variable.
- Add more properties to be asserted in the form of key:value pairs format if needed

```groovy
//Provide / edit the file name to store properties
def propFileName = '/tmp/testCase.properties'

//Define the properties to be matched or asserted ; add more properties if needed
def props = [ 'vTIDAPI':'vTIDDB', 'RefAPI':'RefDB', 'AmountAPI': 'AmountDB', 'CurrencyAPI': 'CurrencyDB']

/**
 * Do not edit beyond this point
 */
def writeTestCasePropertiesToFile = {
    //Get the test case properties as Properties object
    def properties =  context.testCase.properties.keySet().inject([:]){map, key ->  map[key] = context.testCase.getPropertyValue(key); map as Properties}  
    log.info properties
    assert properties instanceof Properties
    properties?.store(new File(propFileName).newWriter(), null) 
}

def myAssert = { arg1, arg2 -> 
    context.testCase.getPropertyValue(arg1) == context.testCase.getPropertyValue(arg2) ? null : "${arg1} value does not match with ${arg2}"
}
def failureMessage = new StringBuffer()
props.collect{ null == myAssert(it.key, it.value) ?: failureMessage.append(myAssert(it.key, it.value)).append('\n')}
if(failureMessage.toString()) {
    log.error "Assertion failures:\n ${failureMessage.toString()}"
    writeTestCasePropertiesToFile()
    throw new Error(failureMessage.toString())
} else {
    log.info 'Assertions passed'
}
```

**EDIT: Based on the OP comments**

Replace `def myAssert = ...` with below code fragment.

```
def myAssert = { arg1, arg2 -> 
    def actual = context.testCase.getPropertyValue(arg1)
    def expected = context.testCase.getPropertyValue(arg2)
    actual == expected ? null : "${arg1} value does not match with ${arg2} - api ${actual} vs db ${expected}"
}
```

Comment: Thank you again like always Rao. just one little quick question. Any properties with 'DB' at the end will require a .toString().replace('"', '') at the end as the assertion will fail without it due to the property value surrounded by quotations. Do you know how I can include this in your code?

Comment: Have you tried the above solution? What message do you see on failure? and what do you want if it different from what is shown?

Comment: Error: vTIDAPI value does not match with vTIDDB RefAPI value does not match with RefDB CurrencyAPI value does not match with CurrencyDB

Comment: So what i get if i log error is this as an example for a set of properties I compare against: CurrencyAPI="GBP"
CurrencyDB=GBP. Sorry it's any properties that has API at the end that contains quotations. This is because when we extract data from the API, they all contain quotations but from the DB they don't

Comment: I receive an error stating this: CurrencyAPI value does not match with CurrencyDB - api "GBP" vs db GBP

Comment: It is difficult without data. You need to take care while saving into test case level properties. continue on chat link provided in the question. Please show the respective script where the data is stored.

Comment: I will send you sample data